# How to use javascript to automatically change a div element's background-image hourly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use this script from [shecodesio](https://www.shecodes.io/athena/67661-how-to-change-background-color-based-on-time-of-day-with-javascript) to target and automatically change the background-image of the `.bottombg` div element every 6 hours. I'm already using it successfully for the body's background-image, but it seems that regardless of targeting the different element, the `.bottombg` image does not change. How can I edit this code in order for it to target `.bottombg` and show the images I've included in this script's rotation too?
Sidenote, I'm also aware that I'm getting an error when I run the code in stackoverflow's preview, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change in those lines.

```css
*, *::after, *::before { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* removes empty space at the bottom of the entire page */
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* entire page */
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url('https://files.catbox.moe/jn5kb6.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* css grid for container positions */
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 5fr) minmax(0, 4fr);
    justify-items: center;
    gap: 6em;
    height: 98%;
}

/* top container */
.top {
    height: 85%;
    aspect-ratio: 990 / 644;
    /* top left bottom right */
    margin: 5% 0% 0px 4%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  }

/* top container in firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.top {
    /* top left bottom right */
    margin: 3% 0 0 24%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
}

/* top container background */
.topbg {
  background-image: url('https://files.catbox.moe/je4qpd.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 990 / 687;
    margin: 6vh auto 0 auto;
}

/* posts inside container */
.content {
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: transparent;
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    /* top right bottom left */
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    margin-top: 0vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/* bottom container */
.bottom {
    height: 85%;
    aspect-ratio: 974 / 559;
    /* top left bottom right */
    margin: 5% 0% 0px 6%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
    
/* bottom container in firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.bottom {
    /* top left bottom right */
    margin: 3% 0 0 24%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
}

/* bottom container background */
.bottombg {
  background-image: url('');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 974 / 559;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>

<!-- scripts -->

<!-- css -->
<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>

<body>

<main>
    <div class="topbg">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="content">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


<!-- scripts -->
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://static.tumblr.com/qxrkgx6/q6kmgn2w2/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- body background -->
<script>
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const date = new Date();
const hour = date.getHours();                   /*
extra info:
> sign means "after" and < sign means "before" 
hours before 6am = night
hours before 12pm = day
hours before 6pm = afternoon
hours before 12am = night                       */
if (hour < 6) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/6noap6.png')";}
else if (hour < 12) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/jn5kb6.png')";}
else if (hour < 18) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/oerw11.png')";}
else {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/6noap6.png')";}
</script>

<!-- bottombg background -->
<script>
const body = document.querySelector('.bottombg');
const date = new Date();
const hour = date.getHours();                   /*
extra info:
> sign means "after" and < sign means "before" 
hours before 6am = night
hours before 12pm = day
hours before 6pm = afternoon
hours before 12am = night                       */
if (hour < 6) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/9q12il.png')";}
else if (hour < 12) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/jxrszb.png')";}
else if (hour < 18) {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/5alsaz.png')";}
else {
  body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://files.catbox.moe/jxrszb.png')";}
</script>

    </div> <!-- <div class="topbg"> -->
        </div> <!-- <div class="top"> -->
            </div> <!-- <div class="content"> -->
        
    <div class="bottombg">
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="content">
                    
    </div> <!-- <div class="bottombg"> -->
        </div> <!-- <div class="bottom"> -->
            </div> <!-- <div class="content"> -->

</main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have your script before the actual element is rendered - either move the script to the end before the closing body tag or put it into a document ready event handler

Comment: Thank you!! A document ready event handler seemed to work perfectly!